# Why does the Product\Collection not respect the page-number and page-size attributes?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

I'm trying to get a list of all the products in the store using the product-collections but it doesn't respect the page and page-size params. I'm using the sample data and have 174 products in my store but irrespective of the page number and size supplied when querying the collection:

```
/** @var Store $store */
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore(true);
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->getCollection($store);
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection = $collection->setCurPage(100);
$collection = $collection->setPageSize(1000);
$collection = $collection->load();

var_dump($collection->getSize());
//var_dump($collection->count());
//var_dump(count($collection->getData()));
```

I've tried to output the size of the collection after querying it but the number of results are incorrect.

Comment: if you are running this on frontend you have to make sure that all the products are enabled in stock and assigned to the website. Otherwise, you might be reading data from the flat tables which don't contain the disabled products and the ones not associated to the current website.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the definition of `getSize` (it's in `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb`). You'll see the following:

```
public function getSize()
{
    if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

The method `getSelectCountSql` does exist in the original class, but if you follow it down:

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    return $this->_getSelectCountSql();
}
```

To:

```
protected function _getSelectCountSql($select = null, $resetLeftJoins = true)
{
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = is_null($select) ? $this->_getClearSelect() : $this->_buildClearSelect($select);
    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
    if ($resetLeftJoins) {
        $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

To:

```
protected function _buildClearSelect($select = null)
{
    if (null === $select) {
        $select = clone $this->getSelect();
    }
    $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
    $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::COLUMNS);

    return $select;
}
```

You'll see that `getSize` will always reset the LIMIT and perform a MySQL query to give you the size of the full collection (assuming I didn't miss somewhere that sets `_totalRecords` outside of that method). Given that you've already loaded the collection, calling `count($collection)` should result in the right number.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Calling count on the collection after I commented out all my other size methods, it still returned the same number of items.